# how to create an html href with added php variable

Tags: php, variables, href

How can I attach a php variable to an href link?

Been trying but not working

```
<li>
    <a href="login.php?lang='<?php echo $lang; ?>'"><?php echo $lang['sign_in'];?></a>
</li>
```

The problem is in this part --> ... `<?php echo $lang; ?>`

Anyone know what to do?

Thank you for your help

Comment: And what are you seeing? What exactly isn't working? THe is nothing specifically wrong with the code you've provided, but  it doesn't tell us much.

Comment: No need single quotes enclosed in variable  `<li><a href="login.php?lang=<?php echo $lang; ?>"><?php echo $lang['sign_in'];?></a></li>`

Comment: Closing this as a typo.  The OP is using the correct syntax with the tag's text, just not with the href.  This would have caused php to scream Array to String.  This is unreasearched.  Finding a duplicate is pointless because the correct syntax is used in the tag text.

Answer (score 0):

No need single quotes enclosed for `$lang` variable

```
<li><a href="login.php?lang='<?php echo $lang; ?>'"><?php echo $lang['sign_in'];?></a></li>
```

Change To

```
<li><a href="login.php?lang=<?php echo $lang; ?>"><?php echo $lang['sign_in']; ?></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

$lang is a array variable.to assign declare variable with key value with `$lang`. and No need single quotes enclosed for `$lang` variable.

Try this:

```
<li><a href="login.php?lang=<?php echo $lang['sign_in'] ?>"><?php echo $lang['sign_in'];?></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a array value not possible to pass in anchor tag. If you need all array values into another page use following code

index.php

```
<?php
   $lang = array("php","c","c++");
$Text = json_encode($lang);
$RequestText = urlencode($Text);
?>
<a href="second.php?id=<?php echo $RequestText; ?>">Click</a>
?>
```

second.php

```
$Text = urldecode($_REQUEST['id']);
$Mixed = json_decode($Text);
print_r( $Mixed);
?>
```

Comment: if I have an array with a single value lets say "us" I get this link ... login.php?lang=%5B%22us%22%5D ... do you know why?

Comment: can you provide an example or is it the same as above?

Comment: We are passing string values into url. So need urlencode and urldeode. Please refer this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php and